# Java - reading text file and transforming lines into class values

Tags: java, class, jframe

So here is the thing. I want to set up a reader that would allow me to implement some numbers into class values. Sounds complicated for me or I just don't know how to write in english. 
Time for some examples. I want my text file to look like this:

```
Hello world      //This is some random text that I will use in my JFrame
Hello world      //Just like above
15               //Some random numbers that I will use as values in my class
32               //Just like above
76               //Just like above
```

I already read the other guides for scanners (http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html for example) but it's still pretty hard to write something on my own. I need some tips and maybe some code from you guys.

Comment: `implement some numbers into class values` What does it mean?

Comment: What is a "class value"? There are too many things this could mean; please post the code you're trying to make work, such as the class(es) you're trying to store the values in.

Answer (score 0):

here is a [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) shwoing you how to use properties files.  The properties that you read in from a file can be used to set values in your classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you simply want to know when you've encountered a number and not text from your file?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
{
    try
    {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
        // no exception? It's a number
    }
    catch ( NumberFormatException e )
    {
        // exception? It's text
    }
}
br.close();
```